# C++ include guards for function prototype?

Tags: c++

I do know that include guards are to prevent redefinition. But does function prototype needs include guards too (supposedly that function prototype is defined in a header and used in multiple related programs)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declarations aren't definitions, so you can repeat declarations as many times as you want. E.g. a file with just:

```
int f(int);
int f(int);
int f(int);
int f(int);
```

is totally legal.

Comment: Prototype is not definition. So i guess it's ok to declare it on header and include as many times in related program files. Did i get it right?